# Is there a way to do half of a newline?

Tags: objective-c, unicode, nsstring, ascii

I'm wondering, is there a way to do half of a new line character (`\n`) in an `NSString` in objective C, i.e. so that it only skips about half the space? Or anyway else to accomplish this in an `NSString`?

Comment: What do you mean with "do half of a newline" ? Waht do you want to achieve ?

Comment: @aleroot - I mean half of the space that a new line would normally produce. I have some bullet points, and I want to leave just a little bit of space between the bullets, and the text leading into the bullets. A regular newline is too much space, about half that is right.

Comment: Have you looked at `NSParagraphStyle`?

Comment: @Wain - Nah, I will now though thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Wain said, setting NSParagraphStyle on an NSAttributedString might be what you are looking for. UILabel supports NSAttributedStrings in iOS 6, but anything before that you will have to use a third party component. [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel) is very good and well documented.

```
NSMutableAttributedString* attrStr = [NSMutableAttributedString attributedStringWithString:@"Hello World!"];
NSMutableParagraphStyle *style = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
[style setLineSpacing:24]; //Just a random value, you'll have to play with it till you are hhappy
[attrStr addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName
                  value:style
                  range:NSMakeRange(0, [myString length])];
label.attributedText = attrStr;
```

if you end up using `TTTAttributedLabel` you would use `label.text = attrStr;` or one of the helper methods (Taken from `TTTAttributedLabel` docs:

```
[label setText:text afterInheritingLabelAttributesAndConfiguringWithBlock:^ NSMutableAttributedString *(NSMutableAttributedString *mutableAttributedString) {
  NSRange boldRange = [[mutableAttributedString string] rangeOfString:@"ipsum dolar" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
  NSRange strikeRange = [[mutableAttributedString string] rangeOfString:@"sit amet" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

  // Core Text APIs use C functions without a direct bridge to UIFont. See Apple's "Core Text Programming Guide" to learn how to configure string attributes.
  UIFont *boldSystemFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
  CTFontRef font = CTFontCreateWithName((__bridge CFStringRef)boldSystemFont.fontName, boldSystemFont.pointSize, NULL);
  if (font) {
    [mutableAttributedString addAttribute:(NSString *)kCTFontAttributeName value:(id)font range:boldRange];
    [mutableAttributedString addAttribute:kTTTStrikeOutAttributeName value:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] range:strikeRange];
    CFRelease(font);
  }

  return mutableAttributedString;
}];
```

Also, `TTTAttributedLabel` has a `lineHeightMultiple` (between 0.0 and 1.0) property that you might be able to fiddle with to get the desired effect. That way, you'll still be able to use an `NSString` and not mess with the sometimes ugly `NSAttributedString`.

Answer (score 1):

While this answer arguably won't help the asker, some historical perspective on the half-linefeed concept may be of general use.

The concept of half-reverse and half-forward linefeeds was useful on teletypes to combine, say, the `o` and `"` characters to approximate the German "o umlaut", ö. The Unix [`col`](https://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man1/col.1.asp)  command recognized ESC-8 (0x1b 0x38) and ESC-9 (0x1b 0x39) as these sequences, respectively, and this standard was adopted by [`asciitiff`](http://www.faximum.com/fms/docs/asciitiff.htm).

The printer control language PCL recognized the forward half-linefeed.
An OKI PCL4.5 printer, the [OL600e](https://my.okidata.com/idocs2.nsf/0/1fa14d9e2b3a9a5f85256ba700521ba0), accepted `ESC=` (0x1b 0x3d) as half-linefeed, and [PCL5](https://www.microfocus.com/documentation/extra/9-6/user-guide/printer-scs-pcl5-control-sequences-ch.htm) extended that to `ESC&=` (0x1b 0x26 0x3d).

I'm having difficulty locating older examples.